# jquery slide menu - better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to javascript/jquery and I just built a simple slide menu.

It has 3 menus and each menu has a submenu...everything is working fine, I just want to know if there's a better way to accomplish the same task.

Here's my js code:

```
function menuOpen(menu){
    if(menu=='menu1'){
        $("#sub2").slideUp(400);
        $("#sub3").slideUp(400);
        $("#sub1").slideToggle(400);
    }else if(menu=='menu2'){
        $("#sub1").slideUp(400);
        $("#sub3").slideUp(400);
        $("#sub2").slideToggle(400);
    }else if(menu=='menu3'){
        $("#sub1").slideUp(400);
        $("#sub2").slideUp(400);
        $("#sub3").slideToggle(300);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/ - no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: agree with @DevlshOne - or maybe even http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**without seeing your HTML**:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uweser/2/edit)**

```
function menuOpen(menu){      
    var num = menu.match( /\d+/ ); // Regex expression to retrieve the Number                 
    $('[id^=sub]').slideUp();      // slide UP all ID starting with sub
    $('#sub'+num).slideToggle();   // get the desired ID :)  
}
```

<sub>Use of jQuery means that we want to **easily** manipulate DOM elements , which means that without seeing a HTML sample of your DOM nodes and structure you're about to target it's hard to make the above **even simpler**.</sub>